# Replacing faucet copper pipes with stainless steel, need help

Tags: bathroom, pipe, faucet, copper

I wanted to install a hot and cold water bidet on my toilet, so I need to get hot water from the pipes feeding into my faucets. The issue is that the pipes from the valves to the faucet are all copper, so I can't just install the included T joint (unless I can?). So I want to replace the copper with a  braided stainless steel one from amazon:

KES IUS2024-P2 Faucet Connector, Braided Stainless Steel - 3/8" Female Compression Thread x 1/2" I.P. Female Straight Thread, 24" Length x 2 Pcs (1 Pair)

The issue I have now is that the faucets itself uses copper pipes, so I need to somehow connect the stainless steel pipes to the copper one.

I clearly don't know anything about pipes, so any help would be great. I also thought about just replacing the faucet out right, but I kinda like my current one.

[image: The copper pipes in question]

[image: Valves]

Comment: Why don't you cut the copper and sweat in tees? That old copper is going to have a lot more mileage in it than any braided connector...

Comment: You say there is an included tee, what tubing will it fit? I assume it is a compression, right?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is gets the appropriate tee for the job.

**This tee allows you to connect two compression output to one input**

[image]

www.homedepot.com

1. Turn off the water and open the taps.
2. Unscrew the copper and gently bend it to allow space for the tee.
3. Attach the tee and connect the copper to the tee at the most convenient branch.
4. Attach the braided stainless to the other branch.
5. Open the valves, check for leaks, close the taps, check for leaks and done!

Answer (score 0):

Is the bidet a new one or are you trying to add a bidet to an existing toilet, which would be quite a feat; I have never seen or heard of this being done. For the connection You could go to Home Depot and ask for a brass craft valve SKU# 234717, model # CR190LRX R1. This valve or a similar  one may solve your problem for making the transition. As threePhaseEel suggested you may want to solder tees into the existing tubing.  You may also  have problems with the existing connections at the valves since there is a fair amount of corrosion around the compression nuts. The copper pipe from the valves at the wall up to the sink valves was soft (flexible ) pipe, which by its very nature tends to be out of round, making it extremely hard to fit copper fittings to it for soldering if you decide soldering is your best option. You may be better off getting someone versed in plumbing to help. Good luck.

Comment: Dual outlet valve would better than T's especially for someone that had limited experiance sweating copper. , standard 3/8 fittings will allow for easy off the shelf purchase of the braided stainless line to the bidet, the only concern I can think of is it will take a while to have warm water even if you run the sink until warm unless the bidet has a heater, I have only installed a couple of these and 2 were for the same person the second had a heater so the water was at the thermostat set point.